# error during Haar Training with TBB using traincascade.exe

Tags: opencv

I have about 931 cropped positive samples and 1162 negative samples(non object of interest). The cropped images have a resolution of 54x12 and are placed in a folder. The .txt file containing the positive samples looks something like this : picture1.bmp 1 0 0 54 12 .  I have a .txt file for negative imagesthat contains only name of negative images like Noneye001.bmp.

Command Used:
1.For .vec file generation

```
C:\Opencv2.4.3\opencv\build\bin\Debug\opencv_createsamplesd.exe -info positive/info.txt -num 931 -vec data/vector.vec -maxxangle 0.6 -maxyangle 0 -maxzangle 0.3 -maxidev 100 -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -w 54 -h 12
```

2.For Haartraining

```
C:\Opencv2.4.3\opencv\build\bin\Debug\opencv_traincascaded.exe -data data/cascade -vec data/vector.vec -bg negative/infofile.txt -numPos 931 -numNeg 1162 -numStages 20 -precalcValBufSize 256 -precalcIdxBufSize 256 -featureType HAAR -mode ALL -w 54 -h 12
```

I getting following error

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: data/cascade
vecFileName: data/vector.vec
bgFileName: negative/infofile.txt
numPos: 931
numNeg: 1162
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 256
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 256
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 54
sampleHeight: 12
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: ALL

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   931 : 931
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    1162 : 1
Precalculation time: 41.787
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3| 0.996778| 0.300344|
+----+---------+---------+
END>

===== TRAINING 1-stage =====
<BEGIN
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Can not get new positive sample. The most possible r
eason is insufficient count of samples in given vec-file.
) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\apps\traincascade\imagestorage.cpp, line 15
9
```

I tried increasing and decreasing no. of negative samples but it didn't help.

Please help.......
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have 931 positive images and are trying to train 931 for the positive stage.

You need to reduce this number as on each training stage for every "Mis classifcation" it will try and get another image.

Turn this down to 800 and see how you get on, I imagine it wont fail.

If you need some more info there is an OpenCVAnswers question on it [Here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/776/error-in-parameter-of-traincascade/)

Answer (score 0):

opencv_createsamples has  a -num parameter that sets the number of positive samples (it doesn't simply read the number of lines in the positive sample file).  The default , if -num is not set, is 1000 samples.  This is why the opencv_traincascade is failing near 1000 samples, due to  there being only 1000 positive examples.
For harder problems you may need more than 1000 samples and thus will need to set the -num parameter.